# Connect Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I am trying to connect Oracle 9i database using SQL Management studio 2008.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'OracleLinkedServer','Oracle','OraOLEDB.Oracle','TestDB';

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'OracleLinkedServer','false','SA','TestUsername','TestPassword';
```

I am able to create the linked server and it test correctly,

But when I execute this statement:

```
SELECT sysdate FROM OracleLinkedServer...dual;
```

...it gives an error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OracleLinkedServer" reported an error. Provider caused a server fault in an external process.
>
> Msg 7311, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES" for OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OracleLinkedServer". The provider supports the interface, but returns a failure code when it is used.

Comment: Do you have the TNS name stuff set up correctly on the SQL Server Box (or are you using the version of the oracle client drivers that use host name resolution)?

Comment: I connect using pl/sql developer to the same oracle database.

Comment: Try to execute this: SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(OracleLinkedServer, 'SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL').

Answer (score 0):

You should UNCHECKED the `Allow inprocess` in OraOLEDB.Oracle provider under the Linked Servers node.